# How to fetch documents from the Mongodb collection in parts for loading by scroll to the React

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model Mongoose:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
const schema = new Schema({
 user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
 message: { type: String }
});
module.exports = model('Comments', schema);
```

How to load data in parts from this collection?I want to load 5 documents with each request, then with a new request the next 5 and so on. What am I doing wrong?

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const userComments = await Comment.find({},{message:{ $slice: [5, 5] }})
      .populate('user', ['avatar', 'firstName'])
      .sort({ $natural: -1 });
```

I tried, but the data comes in completely, not by 5;

it's not working `.find({},{$slice: [5, 5] });`
if i tried:

```
     const userComments = await Comment.find()
      .populate('user', ['avatar', 'firstName'])
      .sort({ $natural: -1 }).skip(5).limit(5);
```

but the same 5 documents are returned with each request;
Part of my collection 'comments':

```
    {"_id":{"$oid":"5e26c87b590ed71b9897dbca"},
    "user":{"$oid":"5e2571ba388ea01bcc26bc96"},
    "message":"wwwwwww","__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}

    {"_id":{"$oid":"5e26c87b590ed71b9897dbca"},
    "user":{"$oid":"5e2571ba388ea01bcc26bc96"},
    "message":"qqqqq","__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) just slices an array, not the entire document collection.

You need to use `$skip` and `$limit` like you have but implement pagination with a `query` parameter.

Meaning when you send your request to the server it should look like this:
`https://myserver?page=1` and on the "next" load `https://myserver?page=2`

On your server side just change to the code to match the query:

```
const PAGE_SIZE = 5;
let skip = req.query.page ? parseInt(req.query.page) : 0;

const userComments = await Comment.find()
    .populate('user', ['avatar', 'firstName'])
    .sort({ $natural: -1 }).skip(skip * PAGE_SIZE).limit(PAGE_SIZE);
```

I also recommend you move the query parameter checks and sanitation to a middleware as it's considered a best practice, I personally use `express-validator`.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that $slice() and skip().limit()  work the same way. Recently started an internship in mongodb .And I thought that when loading comments on the scroll I do not need to pass the number in url

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.limit` you can limit the number of documents and using `.skip` you can skip first fetched records for next set of documents. e.g.

To load first set of documents:

```
find().limit(5);
```

To load next set of documents (2nd page):

```
find().skip(5).limit(5);
```

In this 2nd fetch it will skip the first fetched documents and fetch next set of 5 documents as we specified the limit count as 5.